# Почему не удается получить доступ к смещению типа string в строке?

Tags: php

Уже не первый день ломаю голову и не могу решить ошибку. Код переписывается под php 8.2
Ошибка:

```
[2023-04-29 00:53:02] EngineGP.ERROR: TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in file /var/enginegp/system/library/cron/threads.php on line 30
Stack trace:
  1. TypeError->() /var/enginegp/system/library/cron/threads.php:30
  2. threads->__construct() /var/enginegp/system/library/cron.php:79
  3. include() /var/enginegp/cron.php:47
 [] []
```

Файл в котором возникает ошибка:

https://github.com/EngineGPDev/EngineGP/blob/main/system/library/cron/threads.php
Благодарю за помощь! Испробовал уже многие варианты решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Если `$aUnit[...]` это строка (которая создаётся в строке 18 в этом файле), то попытка присваивания чего-то внутрь строки с помощью `$aUnit[...][...]` выглядит для меня бессмысленной

Comment: Собственно, даже при попытке повторить такое в php 7.4 он мне тоже выбивает ошибку, поэтому я не очень понимаю, как такой код в принципе способен работать и работал ли он когда-либо вообще (ну или я как-то неправильно понял код из-за того, что вы поленились составить [mcve])

Comment: @andreymal код изначально писался под php 5.5 и был портирован на php 7.0. Сейчас же, мигрирую сразу на 8.2. Относительно «Минимально воспроизводимого примера», впервые о таком слышу вообще, спасибо, учту

Comment: У вас в строках 17-18 массив $aUnit заполняется пустыми строками, а на 30-ой вы пытаетесь обратиться к его элементам, как к массивам, предполагая, что а) $server['unit'] элемент тоже массив, б) в нем есть элемент с индексом $server['game'], в) этот элемент строка, к которой можно что-то дописать.

Comment: И еще... К строкам по смещению нельзя ДОписать. Т.е. $str = 'abc'; $str[1] = 'x'; - да, НО: $str = 'abc'; $str[1] .= 'x' - нет.